# How to avoid unnecessary work in list comprehension?

Tags: python

I want to convert string like that:

`"1.2 1.5, 3.2 1.9, 4.4 4.1"`
into
`[(1.2 1.5), (3.2 1.9), (4.4 4.1)]`

I have the following algorithm:

`[(float(x.split()[0]), float(x.split()[1])) for x in s.split(',')]`

How to do just one `x.split()` instead of two?

Comment: The OP algorithm actually has the fastest execution time (3.45 us) compared to all offered solutions (~3.64 us for non-`re` solutions; 5.32 us for `re` solution). IMHO, it is also the simplest and most "Pythonic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant list of tuple of floats (you have comma missing in your representation), you can use `map` to cast a single `.split()` instead of the repetition that you want to get rid of.

```
s = "1.2 1.5, 3.2 1.9, 4.4 4.1"
[tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in s.split(',')]
# [(1.2, 1.5), (3.2, 1.9), (4.4, 4.1)]
```

And if you want to use a generator instead of `map` -

```
[tuple(float(y) for y in x.split()) for x in s.split(',')]
```

You may replace `tuple` with `list` as per need.

Comment: And of course, if they don't want to use `map` they can do `[tuple(float(u) for u in x.split()) for x in s.split(',')]`, but I think `map` is fine here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Little question after this `points = [tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in points.split(', ')]` is it good wat to separate points like that : `lats = [p[0] for p in points]`, `lons = [p[1] for p in points]` ?

Comment: Yeah, that works, but this is even better `lats, lons = zip(*points)`.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the list into different segments, first by using the `","` as the delimiter and then the `" "`

```
s = "1.2 1.5, 3.2 1.9, 4.4 4.1"

new_data = [tuple(map(float, i.split())) for i in s.split(",")]
```

Comment: Your text seems pointless, as that's what he's doing already.

Answer (score 1):

You have to group things anyway, so the only thing to shorten is to remove the explicit handling of the inner split:

```
>>> [tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in s.split(',')]
[(1.2, 1.5), (3.2, 1.9), (4.4, 4.1)]
```

Which also makes it adapt to any length of the comma-separated groups.

Answer (score 1):

just one split using `re`:

```
import re
a = "1.2 1.5, 3.2 1.9, 4.4 4.1"
b = re.split(' |, ', a)
res = [tuple(map(float, (b[i],b[i+1]))) for i in range(0,len(b),2)]
```

Comment: @PM2Ring I had a mistake there which is now corrected, your proposal would also make wrong result, try to run it. It would yield `[(1.2, 1.5), (1.5, 3.2), (3.2, 1.9)]` instead of `[(1.2, 1.5), (3.2, 1.9), (4.4, 4.1)]`